# OpenGL/SDL - Use Black Bars Instead of Stretching

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, resolution, stretch

I'm making a game and it runs at 256x224. I set the actual screen resolution to the user's screen resolution and set the matrix resolution to 256x224. It 'works', but instead of having black bars, it's stretched. How do I make it use black bars instead of stretching?

Comment: Checkout `glViewport` https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glViewport.xml

Comment: Just curious: why 256x224?

Comment: Making a game based on an SNES game.